# DataList inside PanelGrid Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to display dynamic grid panel using DataList but the problem is that the grid panel considers the columns of the datalist as one colomn and displays them in one column.
I want just to dispay panelgrid like in static data.
thank to help me.

this is my code

```
  <h:panelGrid columnClasses="align-top, align-top" columns="2">
                    <h:form>    
                        <p:dataList id="parameters" value="#{scriptManagerForm.params}" var="conf" >
                            <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{conf.name}"></h:outputText>
              </p:column> <p:column>
                            <p:inputText value="#{conf.value}" required="true" rendered="#{scriptManagerForm.isText(conf.type)}"></p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                        </p:dataList>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{scriptManagerForm.validateParams()}" value ="Configure"  />
                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

and this is the style css applied on the panel grid

```
 .align-top {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
```

Comment: DataList is one component inside the PanelGrid so it will be displayed in one column only. But can you please be clear about your goal

Comment: thanks for comment, i want to display fields of the form in grid , bat the  from is dynamic so the filelds are generated by a data list.

Comment: Use <p:row> and <p:column> inside the PanelGrid and put the simple h:dataTable for multiple inputs in first row  and keep the button in the second row. Even you can directly use simple h:dataTable for the dynamic input and keep button outside without using PanelGrid

Comment: there are no problem with the button, and i don't want to use data table, even i don't need panelgrid.

Comment: You can go for ui:repeat with your custom html code